# Derivative and extremum

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

I try to solve a problem but I just can't figure it out:

I have this equation as a statement:

$f(x)= x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

There is a maximum at $x=0$

There are four propositions and one is supposed to be true (apparently the second one):

- $d=0$ and $b>0$
- $c=0$ and $b<0$
- $c=0$ and $b>0$
- $d=0$ and $b<0$

I get why d doesn't matter as the first derivative of the function will make it disappear anyway.

I get why c should equal to $0$ because it needs to be so that the first derivative equals $0$ when $x=0$.

But I really don't get why b should necessarily be $<0$ to make this max possible for this $f(x)$ equation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the second derivative at $0$. To get a maximum, $f''(0)$ has to be negative. If $f''(0)$ is positive, then you have a minimum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I suspect it has to do with the second derivative here but I just don't know how to use it because the second derivative gives me $2(6x^2+3ax+b)$. $a$ and $b$ being constant variables I don't know how to find the roots of this equation so that I can draw a table out of it.
So basically, I know how it should work in theory but with no real values I'm just stuck.

Comment: Remember to plug in $x=0$. **There is a maximum at $x=0$**

Comment: If I do, I get $y=2b$ for my second derivative.
And I don't know what to do with that.
I'm sure it's pretty stupid but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You get $f''(0)=2b$, which has to be less then $0$, so $b<0$

Comment: So far so good until the last statement. And that's my problem.
When I see $f″(0)=2b$, I just don't see why b has then to be $<0$.

Why $f''(x)$ should be negative to begin with?

Comment: Ok got it, thanks! Of course! it has to be so that the curve is concave around the extremum (because it is a max point).
Thank you!